# Passing objects as parameters into functions in Python

Tags: python, class, object, parameters, arguments

I am a newbie in Python, I have used only VBA so far. I would like to know if there is a way to pass instances of a class object into a function as a parameter/argument. I want to have something like what I have reproduced below

```
#ClassOne.py 
class Spnt(object):
    def __init__ (self, wl, val):
    self.wl = wl
    self.val = val


#AnotherFile.py 
    import ClassOne
    def func(obj1, obj2) 
#where obj1 and obj2 are instances of the object     Spnt()
# .....code which does some math
#    returns obj3 which is another instance of the Class object Spnt()
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: Did you *try this out for yourself*?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is for closures and decorators i will give a simple example here:

```
#Decorators are an example of closures

def decorator(function_as_parameter):
    def wrapped_function():
        print "function is being called"
        function_as_parameter()
        print "function call is finished"
    return wrapped_function

@decorator
def my_function():
    print "Hello Wolrd"

my_function()
```

You can customize how you want important what you andrestand concept what a closure in python is a wrapped fuction inside another one.

Please give your vote I need it